# Sorting Data by One Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, data

Once I put the data through Excel importing, it needs to get sorted by the model number in the ascending way. How can this be done?

This is the data set example:

```
735 G6 Notebook PC
1000 Notebook PC series
1050 G1 Notebook PC
1050 G1 Notebook PC
60 1020 G2
720 Notebook PC series
725 G4
730 Notebook PC series
735 G5
735 G5 Notebook PC
735 G5 Notebook PC
735 G5 Notebook PC series
735 G6 Notebook PC
735 G6 Notebook PC series
740 Notebook PC series
745 G4
745 G5
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide some more details here? Are you importing the data to a SharePoint list? In your example, is all that in 1 column, or split into multiple cells in excel?

Comment: @Ashmer, you can sort your data in two places: 1) in Excel, before the import and 2) in SharePoint after the export.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov thank you for the reply could you guide me on how to do that in the share point.

Comment: @RuneSperre i will spilt in the excel then put in the share point post which it has to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your SharePoint list views to be sorted by default on the column(s) you like. To do this, you must first edit your view. Depending on your SharePoint environment you can find this in one of these places:

[image] [image]

Both will bring you into the same view where you choose which columns to show, which items to display and what you are after - how the items are sorted.

[image]

Here I have set the view to sort on the column called "Balance", in descending order. Then after when the items were modified with the oldest first.

When you are finished editing, scroll to the top or bottom again and press OK.

---

The other way of sorting is to do this on-the-fly, but it will reset the next time you refresh the  page. You do this by clicking the column header and select how you want it to be sorted.

[image] [image]